# Environment Object variables and PartialSheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using [PartialSheet](https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/PartialSheet) with SwiftUI, targeting iOS 15+.

I'm having an issue where all content of the sheet disappears if something is interacted with which uses a variable from an environment object.

```swift
.partialSheet(isPresented: $showSheet, iPhoneStyle: iPhoneStyle) {
    ModalSheet()
        .environmentObject(modalManager)
}
```

In ModalSheet:

```swift
//...
Slider(value: $modalManager.paymentSliderAmount, in: 0...600)
    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture()) //chat GPT suggested this -- doesn't change anything
//...
```

ModalManager:

```swift
class ModalManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var paymentSliderAmount = 200.0
}
```

It does manage to read the values (as the slider begins at 200.0 as is set in the EnvObj) but as soon as I try to change the value, all content disappears. The above is an MRE -- but it also behaves the same with buttons that increment an int variable in an EnvObj too.

Comment: The above is not an MRE -- check out [mre] to see what needs to be included.

Comment: @jnpdx ah ok, my mistake. So I should include the struct signature and the body var of ModalSheet, and show what .partialSheet(... is attached to? Maybe it's not an MRE, but does that mater in this instance?

Comment: You already have one close vote (not me) for not including debugging details, so it's up to you, but without it, you certainly run the risk of closure.

Comment: Seems a bit extreme

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/PartialSheet/issues/149#issuecomment-1122422421

> The issue here is where you've chosen to use attachPartialSheetToRoot(). When PartialSheetTestModel publishes new updates (via the count property in your example), any view that listens to its updates will re-render by running body. If PartialSheetTestView watches PartialSheetTestModel for updates, that means that it will re-run attachPartialSheetToRoot() and that will reset the internal state of the partial sheet.

> The high level idea to fix this would be to use attachPartialSheetToRoot() in a place that won't re-run while your sheet is displayed -- ideally close to the view root. In your specific example, one solution might be to introduce an intermediary view to inject your StateObject so that you can attach the partial sheet at a level that isn't changing when it does. Might be a bunch of workarounds based on your use-case though

I did this, created an intermediary view and attached `.attachPartialSheetToRoot()` and now it works as expected.